# How to navigate back to my View controller on the Storyboard?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, navigation, xib, viewcontroller

I have already set up two buttons that navigate me to "SecondViewController" and "ThirdViewController" but to do this I created .XIB files. These work fine.

I used:

```
-(IB Action) clickButton
{
     ThirdViewController *third = [[ThirdViewController alloc]
                                  initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
     [self presentViewController:third animated:YES completion:NULL];
 }
```

Again, this works fine. My problem is when I get to my "ThirdViewController" and want to set up a back button to take me back to my initial ViewController, it doesnt work because it is on the Main.Storyboard, and it isnt an XIB file. How do I make this work? or must I make an XIB file and get rid of Main.storyboard?

and how do I do this without NavigationController, which I am not using

Comment: For "I have already set up two buttons that navigate me to "SecondViewController" and "ThirdViewController" but to do this I created .XIB files.", where do you set these buttons? In your Main.storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use View instead of .XIB files. They are outdated and are hardly used now. And for Navigation you can use Seague. For this you need to create a button in one View, right click on the button and drag-n-drop it to the View you want to be opened when you click that button. Same can be done with the back button on the next View.

Comment: So you are saying to start over essentially, and don't use .XIB files?

Comment: Yeah. If you have not created much of the things in your app, so its the best thing. I was also stuck in this phase when I started creating apps, due to online tutorials, but have finally switched.

Comment: Can you link me to any videos or anything that will help me learn with the new story board and views? all the videos I see use XIB files

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q4708gVOukc) one too. And mark the answer as correct if this helps you.